# How to preserve text wrapping from WinShell to GitHub

Tags: formatting, windows, wrap, text-decorations, cross-platform

I am using WinShell as editor for my Latex text. I use GiHub to share my test with others. My problem is in my WinShell the text is wrapped correctly. But in GiHub, the text appears not the same. The paragraph appears in one extremely long line. This is causing me problems because when someone edits a word, the whole paragraph is marked as changed instead of that line only.

It seems GitHub is not able to get the wrapping that is done in my WinShell editor. How can preserver the text wrapping mode from WinShell to GiHub?

Comment: Enable line wrapping  in Winshell.  This question  is completely  off-topic.

Comment: @Johannes_B It is enabled already. The problem is there even when line wrapping enabled (which is the default).

Comment: *hard* line wrapping.

Comment: @Johannes_B I could not find anyway to do hard line wrapping in WinShell editor. The only option I see is `options-> Wrap mode` is checked. Any idea?

Comment: No idea.  I don't  use this editor.