# How to enable hard text wrapping in WinShell Latex editor

Tags: formatting, wrap, text, text-decorations

I need to enforce hard text wrapping (i.e. new line after some number of words, say 100). I found that the warpping mode is enabled (`Options-> Wrap Mode`) but it is soft (insert new line for display only, but the actual number of lines does not change except with a new paragraph). How to enforce hard text wrapping in WinShell editor? I could not find a way. Any idea?

Comment: Relared https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435770/how-to-preserve-text-wrapping-from-winshell-to-github?noredirect=1#comment1093269_435770

Comment: Seems to be the same question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432999/how-to-wrap-text-to-limited-number-of-characters-per-line-in-winshell-for-latex

Comment: you should edit the previous question to make it clearer not simply post a new question (now therw are two you could delete the old one)